# In PHPstorm after configuration xdebug, stepover is disabled yet.what should I do? and one addition warning

Tags: php, debugging, configuration, phpstorm, warnings

## Please guide me

### No one here knows how to solve the problem!?

I use PHPstorm 2017.2.4 for php programming.
I configured phpstorm to debug by xdebug for use stepover and stepintro in debugging by jetbrain guid documents but just debugging is enable yet and other options is disable. screen shot of this:

[image]

How can I and What should I check to resolve this problem?
I googled and search in stackoverflow but I couldn't find my answer.

#### Update:

#### I couldn't solve that yet.

#### I explain all steps I have done :

first o all say that I use wamp 2.4 for local host server.(php 5.4.12, apache 2.4.4 , MySQL 5.6.12)

1- install phpstorm for use debugger such as step over an step into debugging.
2- use jetbrain guide documents to install debugger:
first check to find xdebug in wamp directory.
then edit last lines of php.ini file in wamp as following:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable = 1
xdebug.profiler_enable_trigger = off
xdebug.profiler_output_name = cachegrind.out.%t.%p
xdebug.profiler_output_dir = "c:/wamp/tmp"
```

3-Set php interpreter as follow image:
[image]

4-Then validate debugger here that don't disply any warning:
[image]

5-Enable listening for PHP debugger connection

6- Install chrome toolbar JetBrains IDE Support for web debugging.

7- I wentback to PHPstorm to debugging but just debug option was enabled and others was disabled as first image in this post.

In addition, after debugging the codes, the warning : "*PHP Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '.\dref.php' for inclusiondisplay this warning. (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\srn\mrt\req_v.php on line 260*" is displayed, while the same code works well in the WAMP(localhost:80) by Firefox browser.
in all php documents that has code similar to below :

```
include_once ('.\jd.php');
require_once(".\dref.php");
require_once(".\scur.php");
```

Then when I changed path for example ".\dref.php" in require_once to "..\dref.php" debugging dont display above warning ,But this timewhen open web by Firefox(localhost:80-wamp) display Warning: require_once(..\dref.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\srn\mrt\req_v.php on line 26

#### Where do I make mistakes and how should I solve these problems?

## Please guide me

## No one here knows how to solve the problem!?

Comment: Those commands will become active once you are in debug session. Check it out: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm

Comment: I couldn't solve problem.Please read updates of my ask